# Ubercart rule to modify user profile field

Tags: rules, ubercart

I have set up a product and a rule to change the value of a custom profile field. How do I link the ubercart product to the rule so that once a user buys the product, the rule kicks into action and modifies the field?

I created the rule via:

Config->Rules

In the rule UI, I did the following:

Events = Customer completes checkout

Conditions = None

Actions = Set a data value (this is where I set the field value)

Comment: How did you write the rule? Could you explain the rule?

Comment: I have edited my entry to answer your question. Thanks

Comment: The ubercart product will automatically link to the rule and update the field when the customer completes checkout.

Comment: But I have multiple products that have different impacts when purchased. Looking at the rule, it kicks off regardless of which product ("Customer completes checkout"). For only this particular product, I am modifying some fields. I dont want that to happen for other products. So I cannot use "Customer completes checkout".

Comment: In that case. I am not sure if you can use rule.